# how to create threads dynamically using HashMap in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[numThreadsToCreate];
for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i] = new Thread(yourRunnable);
    threads[i].start();
}
```

Above is a way to create threads dynamically using array. But i want to create threads using hashmap as i want to create it whenever i want (so no looping) and want to get track of the threads. So thought of using key & element functionality of the hashmap.

```
 HashMap<String, Queue_Inserter> threadHash = new HashMap<>();
```

Here i have created the hashmap. Queue_Inserter is the name of the thread class i want use. And if i normally create thread this is how it works.

```
Queue_Inserter insert = new Queue_Inserter("Insert", queueHash, mainConfig, keyName);
insert.start();
```

I want those parameters for the thread. queueHash is another hashmap and mainConfig is a JSONObject.
I have tried this far and i dont know how to pass the parameters after this. Please help.

Below is the thread class:

```
public class Queue_Inserter implements Runnable {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;
    HashMap<String, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<JSONObject>> queueHash = new HashMap<>();
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<JSONObject> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    JSONObject config;

    public Queue_Inserter(String name, HashMap<String, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<JSONObject>> queueHash, JSONObject config, String keyName){
        threadName = name;
        this.queueHash = queueHash;
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    }

    public void start (){
        if (t == null){
            t = new Thread (this, threadName);
            t.start ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post Queue_Inserter  code?  you pass to some thread ("Insert", queueHash, mainConfig), you want to pass that thread more parameters while it's active ?

Comment: +1 to @Tal.Bary and furthermore, can you re-write your question because it is very hard to understand what you are asking here...

Comment: I think you asking: How you will pass more data to thread after it has been started.

Comment: No that code is to create thread in normal way (like only one thread). I wrote that to show that to show that those are the parameters used inside that thread. I havent started that thread. That is my question. how to start that thread with those parameters. Ok ill modify the questions with the thread class.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you rewrite your code to use an ExecutorService (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead. Doing this kind of thing by yourself is an invitation to bugs.

Comment: If you use an `ExecutorService` your code will be much cleaner... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: The code is correct. What problem you facing? Any exceptions?

Comment: New thread is being created and started. It will execute run() method of Queue_Inserter, where you can access all your parameters passed to it.

Comment: @Meraman yeah... after that what should i do if i have to pass some value into the mainConfig parameter??

Comment: You can set parameters in config object. The run() method can retrieve set parameters from config object.

Comment: i didnt get it. Do you mean that i can pass objects after creating the thread. What i asked is, say, there will be a mainConfig object passed while creating the thread. And how to pass another mainConfig object later in the process?